# how to call a def that's within a class

Tags: python

So I've defined the initial opening of my game as mainmenu and within that is prints a few things with a few options to choose from such as the dificulty of the levels or they can see help for the game. When they go to help I want them to have the option to go back to the main menu, hence why I made def mainmenu(). However in my helpmenu if statement even though I have stated that if they type menu or Menu that it should call back on mainmenu it doesn't do anything. We have a module that we must use and this is why I have to use things such as p.next() which actually means it's listening for a user input so just ignore that :)

here's the code

```
       def mainmen():
        p.write("Welcome to 'The Great Escape'!\n")
        p.write("\nPlease type what dificulty you would like to play the game,\nthe options     are Easy, Medium or Hard\n")
        p.write("\nHowever, if you need help please type Help for instructions\n")
        p.write(">>>")

        dificulty = p.next()  

        if dificulty == "easy" or dificulty == "Easy":  
            p.clear() 
            p.write("The Great Escape")
            easy() 

        elif dificulty == "medium" or dificulty == "Medium":
            p.clear()
            p.write("The Great Escape")
            medium()

        elif dificulty == "hard" or dificulty == "Hard":
            p.clear()
            p.write("The Great Escape")
            hard()


        elif dificulty == "help" or dificulty == "Help":
            p.clear()
            p.write("Welcome to 'The Great Escape' instructions\n")
            p.write("\nTo complete the level you must move your Turtle around the\nline without touching the line itself\n")
            p.write("\nControls\n")
            p.write("Forward    - 'W'\n")
            p.write("Left       - 'A'\n")
            p.write("Backwards  - 'S'\n")
            p.write("Right      - 'D'\n")
            p.write("\nPlease type 'Menu' to go back to the main menu,\nor 'Exit' to quit the game\n")
            p.write(">>>")

**`here is my help menu if statements, I want it so that if they type Menu or menu they get taken back to the main menu.`** 

helpmenu = p.next()
if helpmenu == "Menu" or helpmenu == "menu":
    p.clear()
    mainmenu()  **<<This should call on the mainmenu but it doesn't??**

elif helpmenu == "Exit" or helpmenu == "exit":
    p.clear()
    p.write("Hope you play soon!")
```

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find the other question...

Comment: I'd  also recommend a good Python book to help you learn the basics. The one that seems best right now, at least of those who are for free, is Zed Shaws "Learn Python the hard way". http://learnpythonthehardway.org/

Comment: You don't even need a class. Just define `mainmenu()` to be a top-level function and simplify your code. (Notice how you don't use `self` inside the method - that's a hint that you don't need it to be a method at all).

Comment: Hi Alex, so I removed the class and def bit and just replaced it with mainmenu() and then my code remained the same underneath, however the code isn't executed when the program is run which is why I was led to doing a class instead because when the code is within the class it runs as soon as the program starts. Any ideas?

Comment: Code which is directly within a class (not inside a function) will run immediately, but so will code at the module level (outside a class). The class serves no purpose here. If you have `def mainmenu():` followed by `mainmenu()` both at the top level, it will definitely execute.

Comment: Hi nmclean, I've just removed the class and so forth and changed it to def mainmenu() and you're correct it executes straight a way. However the problem was trying to call it later on in an if statement, in the if statement for the help menu I have if helpmenu == "Menu" or helpmenu == "menu":
    p.clear()
    mainmenu()

Comment: Sorry that pasted a bit wrong, but on my if statement is helpmenu == "menu" or helpmenu == "Menu" then underneath I added mainmenu() but it doesn't seem to call the mainmenu and display everything again it just stalls with no error

Comment: @nmclean I've now updated the code so you can see what I did.

Comment: If it tried and failed to call your function, you would see an error. There must be a problem in your logic where the code you're expecting to be executed isn't actually being reached. Try to simplify it until you find which piece causes it to stop working.

Comment: I've done it now, I defined mainmenu and I embedded everything and all my if statements including the help menu and help menu if statements and then started off the program with print mainmenu() and all is working now :)

Comment: only took around 4 hours to work out lmao

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate the class into an object:

```
menu = mainmenu()
menu.mainmen()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Lennart unfortunately the Python shell states that menu isn't defined. So I also tried mainmen.mainmenu but it then again states that mainmen isn't defined.

Comment: @Daniel: No, what you say now is incorrect. The first line defines `menu`. It can not say that it isn't defined. You did it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On a general note, before you can call class methods, you have to instantiate that class and then you can call different methods with the dot notation.

Coming back to your case, what is the variable p? Lennart's answer is the way to do it if your code doesn't work it's a problem with your if statements at the bottom. You are executing the statement

```
helpmenu = p.next()
```

and then you are checking the value of helpmenu in your if statement. Without knowing what p is and what its next() method does I can't give a really useful answer but let's say that

```
p.next()
```

returns either "menu" or "exit". In that case you should write the last part of your code as follows:

```
# Note that helpmenu is either "menu" or "exit", so either the if block will be
# executed or the elif block will be executed. 
if helpmenu == "Menu" or helpmenu == "menu":
    p.clear()
    m = mainmenu()
    m.mainmen()

elif helpmenu == "Exit" or helpmenu == "exit":
    p.clear()
    p.write("Hope you play soon!")
```

Having said this, I suggest that you insert a print statement after helpmenu = p.next() so that you can check what the value of helpmenu after that line.

Other stuff I noticed in your code:

- You can use difficulty.lower() == "easy" (and similar for helpmenu) so that you don't have to write all the possible choices.
- Consider adding an else statement to your if blocks. If none of the if/elif blocks are matched, your code will not do anything and the user won't know that they did something wrong.
- Defining a class here is pretty useless. You could just write the mainmen() function on its own it will work. You don't need to create an object for this use.

I hope this helps, if you need any further help, please let me know and I will try to help to the best of my abilities.

Comment: Hi can lbanoglu, that was a very detailed and a great input! however I really have missed the point that people need to know my whole scenario before they can help. So at university they have created a module called Py110 and this contains all the things we can use (its to make sure its not possible to copy paste off the internet as such) So at the start of my code I have p = Py110.Py110 and within that Py110 file we have a huge library of functions and so forth. So when I write >>p.next()<< this is defined so that it reads a string from the keyboard.

Comment: So when I type mainmenu = p.next() it's actually our way of saying mainmenu = the users input. We also have nextInt if we want to listen for a single integer, to do this we would use p.nextInt() I suppose you get the gist now :) But besides that I need to understand how I can create the main menu so that it displays when the game is opened, but I also want a way so that I can call the same code again so I don't end up with blotchy code. Initially I used class mainmenu: and then bunged all the code beneath it and the code was executed at startup but when I tried calling it I got errors

Comment: Ah, you could create a class for the whole game and define the methods medium(), easy() and hard() along with menu() and a run() method so that you can just call the run() method after instantiating the game object.
Another way of doing this would be to modify the difficulty functions so that when they receive input from the user they check if the input is equal to "menu" and if so call the menu function.